# MongoDb Java filter for value in list

Tags: java, mongodb, filter

I have a database object that contains a field which is also an object, like this:

```
public class PrdVersionOverviewDbData {

    public static final String FIELD_SPECIFICATION_ENTRY_POINTER = "specificiationEntryPointer";
    
    @BsonProperty(FIELD_SPECIFICATION_ENTRY_POINTER)
    private MongodbSpecificationEntryPointer specificiationEntryPointer;

    [...]
}
```

Now, I have a `List<MongodbSpecificationEntryPointer>`, and I want to look up all `PrdVersionOverviewDbData` where the `specificiationEntryPointer` is any of the list. Spontaneously, I tried solving that with an `in` Filter like this:

```
Bson filter = Filters.in(PrdVersionOverviewDbData.FIELD_SPECIFICATION_ENTRY_POINTER, specificiationEntryPointerList);
```

However, for some strange reason, running that filter always only returned me an empty list.

By contrast, the following logic gives me the desired result:

```
    public List<PrdVersionOverviewDbData> readPrdVersionsContainingAnyOfSpecificationPointers(
        List<MongodbSpecificationEntryPointer> specificationPointerList
    ) {
        List<PrdVersionOverviewDbData> allPrdVersionOverviews = readObjectList();
        List<PrdVersionOverviewDbData> prdVersionOverviewsContainingSpecificationPointer = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PrdVersionOverviewDbData prdVersionOverviewDbData : allPrdVersionOverviews) {
            if(prdVersionOverviewDbData.containsAny(specificationPointerList)) {
                prdVersionOverviewsContainingSpecificationPointer.add(prdVersionOverviewDbData);
            }
        }
        return prdVersionOverviewsContainingSpecificationPointer;
    }
```

```
public class PrdVersionOverviewDbData{

    public static final String FIELD_SPECIFICATION_ENTRY_POINTER = "specificiationEntryPointer";
    
    @BsonProperty(FIELD_SPECIFICATION_ENTRY_POINTER)
    private MongodbSpecificationEntryPointer specificiationEntryPointer;

    [...]

    public boolean containsAny(
        List<MongodbSpecificationEntryPointer> specificationPointerList
    ) {
        return specificationPointerList.contains(specificiationEntryPointer);
    }
}
```

That is, of course, very inefficient since it first needs to read all the data from MongoDB and then iterate over it. So my question is: What am I doing wrong with the filters? And what would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have now figured out what caused this and how to fix it.

In essence, `Filters.in` is the correct filter to use for this kind of situation. The problem is that for some Objects, MongoDB has trouble comparing them. This *may* be related to said objects being children of abstract classes, but I am not 100% sure about that.

Anyway, how I managed to fix this was that instead of comparing by MongodbSpecificationEntryPointer (which is, in essence, just a wrapper for an ObjectId), I compared directly by the ObjectId, so now my logic looks somewhat like this:

```
    private static final String FIELD_PATH_SPECIFICATION_POINTER_OBJECT_ID
        = PrdVersionOverviewDbData.FIELD_SPECIFICATION_ENTRY_POINTER
            + "."
            + MongodbEntryPointer.MONGO_DB_ID_FIELD;
    
    public List<PrdVersionOverviewDbData> getPrdVersionOverviewsInSpecifications(
        List<Specification> specificationsInFolder
    ) {
        List<ObjectId> specificationObjectIdList
            = toSpecificationObjectIdList(specificationsInFolder);
        
        return readObjectListWithFieldContainingAny(
            FIELD_PATH_SPECIFICATION_POINTER_OBJECT_ID,
            specificationObjectIdList
        );
    }

    public List<T> readObjectListWithFieldContainingAny(
        String fieldName,
        Iterable<?> fieldValue
    ) {
        Bson filter = Filters.in(fieldName, fieldValue);
        return readObjectList(filter);
    }
    
    private List<ObjectId> toSpecificationObjectIdList(
        List<Specification> specificationsInFolder
    ) {
        return specificationsInFolder.stream()
            .map(Specification::getObjectId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```